# handling "abc\xyz" value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have "abc\xyz" value stored in mongodb database.

for eg:

```
{
        "name" : "heater\boostpump"
}
```

when i try to console this value, it shows =

```
"heateroostpump"
```

I want it to be fetched same as it is -

```
"heater\boostpump".
```

thanks.

Comment: \ escapes a character, you need to escape it with another \ to make it work: \\

Answer (score 0):

In a JavaScript string literal, `\b` represents the BACKSPACE ([U+0008](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0008/index.htm)) [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation). I don't know your intentions:

- If you want to print a backspace, you need to consider that it isn't a printable character.
- If you want to print a literal `\`+`b` sequence, you shouldn't be inserting a backspace in the first place:

  ```
  var data = {
      "name" : "heater\\boostpump"
  }
  ```

Comment: I am working on a IOT project. These values are not supposed to be updated on my end. The IOT devices are sending me such data. in my eg: "heater\boostpump" is the value i am receiving for one particular field.

Answer (score 0):

I tried fetching the value using JSON.stringify and then i replaced the double quotes.

It worked for me.

Eg: JSON.stringify("heater\boostpump").replace(/"/g,'');